# What does "homomorphism" require that "morphism" doesn't?

Tags: category-theory, definition, abstract-algebra

I'm starting to learn category theory, but there's one thing I don't get: all morphisms seem to be homomorphisms; the definition seems to be the same. What's the difference between these two? Can you give me an example of a non-homomorphic morphism?

Thank you for your patience,

Comment: Stating the definitions seems appropiate here.

Comment: @GitGud, well, I think they're the same, that is, mappings between mathematical structures that preserve their structure. At least it's what I know so far.

Comment: if homomorphisms are maps between two things of the same "structure", are morphisms really the analogue? i think you'll find functors match far, far better

Comment: @exitingcorpse, analogue? No, I think they're the same.

Comment: I think this is a bit like asking for an example of a group which doesn't have multiplication as its binary operation. If you're going to use a term like 'homomorphism' outside of its usual realm of usage (ie functions which preserve algebraic structures of objects) then you need to define exactly what you mean by 'homormophism' and 'structure preserving'.

Comment: @DanielRust, wait, isn't $\mathbb Z$ with $+$ and $0$ a group (I mean it, I'm not completely sure)? And I already told I think a homomorphism is a mapping between mathematical structures that preserves their structure (their representation as a category, I guess).

Comment: What do you mean by 'structure'? By mapping do you mean function? Because there are many good examples of categories where the arrows are not functions.

Comment: By mapping I mean a relation that when applied to an object of its domain, results in one of its codomain.  A kind of generalized notion of function.

Comment: 'an object of its domain'? The whole point about looking at things in terms of category theory is we view arrows not as these things which map elements from one object to another (ie a function), but as their own entity entirely which only require that they can compose in certain cases. It just so happens that functions and homomorphism have this composition property, which is why we use them as the prototypical example of arrows. It's important to note though that they are just an example. In general arrows do not act on 'elements' of an object, but the entire object all at once.

Comment: @Daniel, now I'm kind of confused. Acting in each element of an object doesn't turn out to be as acting in the whole object?

Comment: In some categories, objects don't even have elements (posets for example or a suitable discrete category). So, it really is better to not think about objects having elements at all.

Comment: @DanielRust, wait. So on another question consider a function $f(x)=x^3-2x^2+9$ in the real numbers. Can it be seen as an identity morphism on the object $\mathbb R$, belonging to a category of all sets possible?

Comment: It depends what the other morphisms are and how composition is defined. The whole point is that a morphism isn't defined by how it acts on elements, but by how it composes with other morphisms (in fact the former can be defined in terms of the latter).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, keep in mind that the term "homomorphism" predates both the term "morphism" and the creation of category theory.

"Homomorphism," roughly speaking, refers to a map between sets equipped with some kind of structure that preserves that structure. The collection of all such structured sets and homomorphisms between them thus forms a category $C$, but this category is itself equipped with some extra structure, namely a faithful functor $C \to \text{Set}$, making it a [concrete category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category).

"Morphism," on the other hand, refers to an arrow in an arbitrary category. In particular, an arbitrary category need not be concretized (and in fact some categories *cannot* be concretized!). Its objects need not be interpreted as sets and its morphisms need not be interpreted as functions: there are many other ways of writing down categories than thinking about structured sets.

Here is an example of a "category where the morphisms are not homomorphisms," but you really shouldn't think of it that way: consider the category whose objects are groups and whose morphisms are all functions (not necessarily preserving the group operations). (The reason I say you shouldn't think of it that way is that, to a category theorist, objects are just placeholders describing how morphisms can compose: all of the important information is in the morphisms, so I have no right to call the objects in this category groups if I can't detect their group structure using morphisms.)

Concretizations of categories are both analogous to and generalize [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). One of the more important habits of thought you can pick up while learning category theory is to think about categories abstractly without choosing a concretization, in the same way that you think about groups abstractly without choosing a group action.

Comment: So homomorphism is like half-way the generalization between a function and a morphism? (BTW, I indeed have heard, actually read, of those concrete categories)

Comment: A function is a structure-preserving homomorphism.  It preserves the structure of being a set (if you think of the groups as being built from sets), or more generally the equality relation between elements of the group.  As you noted, arbitrary functions are not the right notion of morphism in the category of groups, if the latter is intended to capture the usual content of group theory.  But they do not provide a distinction between morphism and homomorphism.

Answer (score 30):

There are already some excellent answers here, but let me add something from a slightly different point-of-view.

First of all, *homomorphism* is not a word that can be used nakedly (so to speak) in mathematics.  It is a function between two structures that preserves their structure, in some sense, and this sense has to be specified as part of the theory of those particular structures. (E.g. in the theory of groups, we define group homomorphisms; in the theory of rings, we define ring homomorphisms, etc.)

Also, in certain contexts, there can be competing notions of homomorphisms (for rings with identity, should the homomorphisms preserve the identity?; for Banach spaces, should morphisms be simply continuous, or should they preserve the norm?); in any particular situation, if it hasn't already been made clear in the context, you have to specify which definition you're using.

Now, in some situations, we *don't* use the word homomorphism; e.g. we don't speak of a homomorphism of topological spaces (instead, we have continuous maps between topological spaces).  The choice of whether or not to use the word homomorphism is to some extent dictated by tradition, and also by general mathematical culture; the more algebraic the structures under consideration are, the more likely the word homomorphism is to be used in regard to them.

Now category theory *abstracts* the notion of mathematical structure and structure preserving maps between them.  As already noted in other answers, not all categories are concrete, or, even if they are, are not naturally thought of as being concrete.  And if we're talking about an arbitrary category, we don't specify what sort of objects the objects actually are; we just write $\mathcal C$, and $x \in\operatorname{Ob}\, \mathcal C$, and $f: x \to y$, without specifying what $\mathcal C$ *is* (just as in the theorems of a group theory text, we don't specify what the group $G$ is or what it's elements $x$ are or what its operation *is*; it is just some abstract, unspecified group).

Now the founders of category theory knew that they were abstracting a situation in which *very often* the category was going to consist of algebraic structures and homomorphisms between them.  But they also knew that they were abstracting examples like topological spaces and continuous maps, where *homomorphism* is *not* the traditional term.  Hence, they chose *morphism* as being close enough to homomorphism to be suggestive, but not identical, so that it didn't give the psychological impression of ruling out contexts like topological spaces and continuous maps.  [This last paragraph is my invention, not actual history, but is probably fairly close to the actual history, and hopefully gets the point across.]

Finally, it seems worth noting that often now in mathematics people speak of a morphism of rings or groups or ..., i.e. they drop the prefix *homo-*, and I think this is the influence of the general category-theoretic terminology.

Answer (score 13):

I will proceed to specify a category $\mathcal{C}$:

- The objects of $\mathcal{C}$ are as follows: $\;\;\mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C})=\{\star,\diamond\}$
- The morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ are as follows:

  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(\star,\star)&=\{\mathrm{id}_{\star}\}& \mathrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(\diamond,\diamond)&=\{\mathrm{id}_{\diamond}\}\\[0.1in]
  \mathrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(\star,\diamond)&=\{\heartsuit\}&\mathrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(\diamond,\star)&=\{\bullet\}
  \end{align*}$$

Are the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ homomorphisms?

(What I'm getting at is: what would it even *mean* to be a homomorphism from $\star$ to $\diamond$?)

Comment: You mean homomorphisms result in objects that belong to the category, while some of those morphisms don't?

Comment: I mean that categories can consist of objects which have no internal structure, and therefore have no corresponding concept of "homomorphisms".

Comment: No? If there's no internal structure, then a homomorphism should preserve it, by when being applied to an object to result in other with absence of structure as well.

Comment: "what would it even mean to be a homomorphism from ⋆ to ⋄?": perhaps some function that transforms objects with no information into different objects with no information?

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? The entirety of information contained in (for example) the morphism $\heartsuit$ is:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\sf\bullet\;\text{ its name}\\
\sf\bullet\;\text{ which object it starts at}\\
\sf\bullet\;\text{ which object it ends at}\\
\end{array}$$
There is no "transforming" going on. The symbol $\heartsuit$ does not (necessarily) denote a function because $\star$ and $\diamond$ don't (necessarily) denote sets.

Comment: Then it would mean a relation between two types of "informationless" objects. Sorry, I was thinking of functions.

Comment: Now I notice, is your avatar bugged?

Comment: Nope - I just like that particular shade of blue :)

Comment: [Guess what my computer wallpaper is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BONWo.png)? :)

Comment: I'll consider using it when I become tired of landscapes. :D BTW, is the last comment on that non-sense homomorphism right?

Comment: @JMCF125 No. There is no such thing as a "relation between informationless objects". Relations exists between sets and are defined as such (usually as subsets of the cartesian product of the sets involved).

Comment: @us2012, why shouldn't there be relations between any objects beyond sets?

Comment: @JMCF125 Because in mathematics, when you use a term, you have to define what it means! You are free to come up with a definition of "relation" between anything, but you *have to have a definition*.

Comment: @us2012, OK, say every informationless object of the same type is equal and those of different types are different.

Comment: @JMCF125 What is the type of an informationless object? Surely a type is a kind of information? Again, you need to get real and hard definitions. This is simplifying the issue a bit, but as a first approximation I would say that the only notions that you are allowed to be a little fuzzy about are 'collection/set/element'. And that's just because these are REALLY hard to *define*, really a philosophical issue. You should be able to define any other term you use in a way the noone can possibly disagree about what it means.

Comment: @us2012, yes, a type is information, however, an instance of it may not contain any actual information. In programming, you can have a type with only a name, such that all instances of it will be equal, and different from each other empty type.

Comment: @JMCF125 I'm trying to come up with a better way of getting my point across but failing so far. In any given programming language, there is a more or less universally accepted definition what a 'type' is and what an 'instance' is. In *this* setting (category theory), these terms mean nothing until you have properly defined them. Analogies do not count as definition.

Comment: @us2012, then I guess I'll have to learn more category theory in order to understand fully what you were saying.

Answer (score 7):

The morphisms in a category do not have to be functions at all, let alone homomorphisms. All that is required of a morphism in a category is to know what its domain and codomain are, and how to compose it with all morphisms in the category.

Examples of categories where morphisms are not functions: Any poset $(P,\le)$ can be considered as a category where the objects are the elements in $P$ and a morphisms $x\to y$ exists iff $x\le y$.

The category $Rel$, whose objects are all sets and a morphisms $f:A\to B$ is a relation, i.e. a subset $f\subseteq A\times B$.

The category $Mat$ whose objects are the natural numbers, and a morphism $n\to m$ is an $n\times m$ matrix (with real entries for simplicity). Composition is matrix multiplication.

Comment: Homomorphisms have to be functions? That's not what I read.

Comment: @JMCF125 what then are homomorphisms?

Comment: They're mappings between mathematical structures that preserve their structure, as I wrote in a comment above. That's why I don't understand what differs them from morphisms.

Comment: mappings are typically taken to be synonymous with functions. Anyways, you should really define your terms then more clearly. Besides, you were already given several examples where morphisms in a category are not structure preserving anything.

Answer (score 2):

The term 'homomorphism' usually refers to structure-preserving maps between algebraic objects like groups, rings, and vector spaces.  Hence, in categories like $\mathbf{Grp}$, $\mathbf{Ring}$, and $\mathbf{Vect}_k$, the morphisms can be called homomorphisms.

But in other categories like $\mathbf{Top}$, the category of all topological spaces, the morphisms are continuous functions, which aren't really referred to as homomorphisms.  In fact, a morphism doesn't need to be a function at all.  Fix a commutative ring $R$.  The category $\mathbf{Matr}_R$ consists of all positive integers as objects, and each $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries from $R$ is regarded as a morphism $A : n \to m$.

So I think you're confused. The term 'homomorphism', whenever applicable,  means the exact same thing as morphism.

Answer (score 1):

Not so.  The definition of a "morphism" depends heavily on the category in question - in fact, it is part of the *definition* of the category.

So, for instance, you could consider the category $SET$, where the objects are sets and the morphisms between sets $A$ and $B$ are simply all the functions possible between the two sets.

Comment: but functions between sets are 'homomorphisms'. It's just that there is no structure to preserve, so all functions preserve structure.

Comment: I don't mean in a specific category. I mean, generally, isn't there a difference between those two? Kind of in the way there is a different definition of epimorphism and monomorphism.

Comment: You could certainly look at it that way.  But you could also define a class where the objects are finite abelian groups and the morphisms are still simply all functions between them as sets.  You won't see things like this terribly often, because morphisms that preserve structure tend to be more useful. However, all that is required of morphisms is that there be an identity morphism for each object and that morphism composition be associative.