# What's the term for my function's aspect of equivalence structure preservation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, group-homomorphism, morphism

$A, B$ are two sets, $\equiv$ is an binary equivalence relation on $A$, and $f  : A \rightarrow B$ is a function. If $x \not \equiv y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$, what does that make $f$?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438384/22998) suggests that

> "Homomorphism," roughly speaking, refers to a map between sets equipped with some kind of structure that preserves that structure.

and my equivalence relation is a structure $A$ is equipped with, and $f$ preserves it - after a fashion. But there's no group, or vector space, which would let me say $f(x \circ y) = f(x) \circ f(y)$.

The [Wikipedia page for Equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) says:

> if $x_1 \sim x_2$ implies $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $f$ is said to be a *morphism* for $\sim$

But I have the converse of that.

So, what would I call a function like $f$?

Answer (score 2):

A working mathematician would probably say something like "the induced map $\hat{f}:A/\!\!\equiv\; \rightarrow B$ is injective" for this condition. Something like that.

**Edit.** As the OP points out, what I just wrote is incorrect; no such map is necessarily induced, because we're not assuming that $f$ turns $\equiv$ into $=$. Given this, I don't think there's a standard way of writing the condition of interest. But you could still say something like: "the induced relation $\hat{f} : A/\!\!\equiv\,\, \rightarrow B$ is injective.

In more detail: given an equivalence relation $\equiv$ on a set $A$, write $[\equiv]: A \rightarrow A/\!\!\equiv$ for the corresponding projection. We get a corresponding relation $[\equiv]^\dagger : A/\!\!\equiv \,\,\rightarrow A$. The condition you're looking for is that the relation $f \circ [\equiv]^\dagger : A/\!\!\equiv\,\, \rightarrow B$ is injective, or in other words that the relation $[\equiv]\circ f^\dagger$ is [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_(category_theory)#Maps_in_allegories.2C_and_tabulations).

Comment: But no such map is induced. I mean, the reduced relation may not be a function, since the implication I described is not bidirectional.

Comment: @einpoklum, you're completely correct. I've edited with some further thoughts.