# how to view a set as a discrete category

Tags: category-theory

Let $S$ be a set. I want to build a discrete category out of $S$. So I take $S$ itself as class of objects; for any two elements $u,t$ of $S$, I say that the set of morphisms from $u$ to $t$ is the empty set when $u$ and $t$ are different elements of $S$, the set $\{1_u\}$ when $u=t$

My question is: what is $1_u$? Just the set mapping $1_u:\{u\}\longrightarrow \{u\}$ or any function defined on the whole of $S$, fixing $u$?

Comment: $1_u$ is really nothing apart from being $1_u$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I usually consider identity morphisms $1_u$ when $u$ is a set, as mappings mapping each element of $u$ to itself. But here $u$ is an element, hence my difficulty

Comment: There is no need to think of $1_u$ as being a mapping here.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   so what is it?

Comment: It's $1_u{{{}}}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So maybe a matrix, or a table?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown think I finally got what you meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly. You have a set $S$ and want to form a category $\mathcal{C}$ where the objects are singletons of $S$ and the morphisms are only identity morphisms on the singletons. Then $1_u:\{u\}\to \{u\}$ is a set theoretic map $1_u(u)=u$.

---

Otherwise though. If you just want to take each element of $S$ and let it be an object. Then $1_u:u\to u$ is just a morphism, where the source map $s(1_u)=u$ and the target map $t(1_u)=u$, and nothing more needs to be said.

Comment: Got it. And what if I say: $1_u:S\longrightarrow S$, where $1_u(t)=$ what you want when $t\neq u$ and $1_u(t)=u$ when $t=u$?

Comment: $S$ is not an object of either category, so $1_u$ isn't defined for what you have written. The morphisms are only defined between objects of the category

Comment: Yes sorry, I wrote a nonsense

Comment: suppose I use what you said after 'otherwise'. How can I check category axioms if I didn't define what the morphism $1_u$ is?

Comment: @bateman What do you mean? You have a class of objects. You have a class of morphisms. Each morphism has a well defined source and target. Composition holds vacuously. Associativity holds by checking compositions of the identity morphism. The identity morphism exists for each object. So we are done.

Comment: @bateman You can think of a morphism fundamentally as an arrow, and nothing more.

Comment: Yes, I think I got, thank you

Comment: @bateman No problem. It's definitely strange when you first deal with these. I think this might be a good read: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/438344/476584

In particular Qiaochu's excellent answer.